# internal/fs error when building in maven

Tags: windows, maven, npm-install

I'm getting the followig error when I try to build a project using

```
mvn clean install
```

initially it asked me to install npm and gulp and I did but now I don't know how to fix the following error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (build-javascript) @ webapp ---
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:18:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hisg417\git\myproject\webapp\node_modules\gulp-bower\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

I have searched for this error but couldn't find a solution.
Here are the details of my enviroment:
Windows 7

I'm running these commands against the project that I'm trying to build and

I get this

```
npm 4.5.0
node 7.0.0
gulp local 3.9.1
     cli   3.9.1
```

Anything I can do to fix it?

PS: Thanks, I think changing the version fixed it but I am now getting this error

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    src\main\webapp\designers\sass\mh-objects.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap
       Parent style sheet: C:/Users/username/git/myproject/webapp/src/main/webapp/designers/sass/mh-objects.scss
        on line 4 of src/main/webapp/designers/sass/mh-objects.scss
>> @import "bootstrap";
   ^
```

I have installed bootstrap-sass and gulp-sass(thought this is the issue) but the error is still persisting. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to upgrade `graceful-fs` to version 4 if you can
2. Try to downgrade `node` to latest 6.x version beacuse version 7 is known to have issues with `graceful-fs`.

You will need probably delete `node_modules` folder in order to install different version.

Comment: Following a course right now and wasted a so much time as it suggested to installed the latest version of npm i.e. 8.4.0 as of today, and kept getting the internal/fs error. Added path as suggested as their setup isn't doing it, even though the options were selected and no luck, then I uninstalled and installed version 6.11.3 and the second I did that it worked as expected!